# Getting related foreign keys from parent entities

Tags: database, database-design, orm, model

I'm thinking about a design issue which affects my project's data base. Supposing there are three diferent tables:

- CLIENT
- ORDER
- PACKING_SLIP

---

Each **order** has its **client** and different **packing slips**. So there are some foreign keys which are compulsory, there would be *clientId* for the `ORDER` and *orderId* for the `PACKING_SLIP` table. That makes full sense.

[image: First diagram]

Now suppose in my logic I want to have access to the client from the packing slip. As I'm using an ORM tool as Hibernate, that involves firstly accessing the order from the packing slip and after getting the client from it.

If I want to have access to the client directly, I should add the *clientId* foreign key also to the `PACKING SLIP` table.

[image: Second diagram]

My question is, is that a correct design if there's a possibility to get the client joining the `ORDER` table? Isn't it a bit redundant? I think it's a control problem and the data base part shouldn't take care about it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's bad design.

Why? Not only it is redundant, but also allows for inconsistencies, i.e., insert, update or delete anomalies.

**You could have a packing slip pointing to a client which is different to the one its order points to.**

If that happens, a query that joins through `ORDER` will fetch a different customer that a query that doesn't.

**That's because you are violating [2NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form).**

**If you want to avoid having to join through `ORDER` every time, create a view** and select that view. The view still have the join but you will not see it.

In non-transactional databases like data warehouses, you don't have to respect normal forms, but in an [OLTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_transaction_processing) databases like yours seems to be, you will have a lot of headaches if you don't. Obviously there are exceptions, but that's not the case with `CLIENT`, `ORDER` and `PACKING_SLIP`.

Comment: Makes sense. If I add `clientId` to the PACKING SLIP, I am able to have different client id to the client id used in the ORDER table. Definitely I must guarantee this consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you'd do exactly what you've described -- have `clientId` in ORDER and `orderId` in PACKING SLIP, and join the two tables to geth the `clientId` for the PACKING SLIP.  Unless you have a really performance critical application, or unless you have a large number of orders, packing slips or clients, this is not a problem.

If you're really worried about performance, there is nothing wrong with adding `clientId` to the PACKING SLIP, though that would require adding code (or other logic) to ensure that `clientId` in PACKING SLIP will stay consistent with `clientId` in ORDER.  This may be best in situations when the application frequently needs to access `clientId` from PACKING SLIP without getting a corresponding ORDER and if you will be updating `clientId` in ORDER rarely.

Ideally this would be done using a stored procedure on the DB side, where updating an ORDER or adding a PACKING SLIP would be done through a stored procedure that will enforce the consistency of `clientId`, but I'm not sure whether your ORM allows that.  Alternatively, some ORMs provide a way to add such logic through code.

Comment: If you do denormalize, you need to maintain the client_id through triggers on all the relevant tables. It is the only way to ensure consistency no matter how the data is changed. (There is an exception for bulk inserts which can avoid triggers but peopel doing this type of thing generally know to reproduce the trigger code they are avoiding after inserting or updating the ten million records.)